# Preventing KStream from emiting old unchanged aggregate value

Tags: apache-kafka, aggregation, apache-kafka-streams

I have a `KStream` pipeline which groups by key and then windows on some interval and then applies a custom aggregation on that:

```
KStream<String, Integer> input = /* define input stream */

/* group by key and then apply windowing */
KTable<Windowed<String>, MyAggregate> aggregateTable = 
    input.groupByKey()
         .windowedBy(/* window defintion here */)
         .aggregate(MyAggregate::new, (key, value, agg) -> agg.addAndReturn(value))

// I need to get a change log of aggregateTable so:
aggregateTable.toStream().to("output-topic");
```

The problem is that majority of the input records will not change the internal state of `MyAggregate` object. The structure is similar to:

```
class MyAggregate {

    private Set<Integer> checkBeforeInsert = /* some predefined values */
    private List<Integer> actualState = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAggregate addAndReturn(Integer value) {

        /* for 99% of records the if check passes */
        if (checkBeforeInsert.contains(value)) {
            /* do nothing and return. Note that the state hasn't been changed */
            return this;
        } else {
            actualState.add(value);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

However, `KStream` doesn't have any clue that the aggregate object hasn't been changed, it still stores the aggregate (which is same as old). It also propagates to same old value to changelog topic and also triggers `aggregateTable.toStream()` with the same old value.

Although the semantic of my application works fine (the rest of application is aware of this fact that unchanged state might arrive), but this creates a huge noise traffic on intermediate topics. I need a way to notify `KStream` whether an aggregate has been really changed and should be stored or it's the same as previous record (just ignore it).

Comment: I would recommend to use the Processor API and build the aggregation manually. This way, you can call `context.forward()` only if the aggregation result changed.

Comment: As an alternative, you could "de-duplicate" downstream via `.toStream().transform()`. For deduplication example compare: https://github.com/apache/kafka -- however, de-duplication will store each key-value pair twice (once in the aggregation store and once in the deduplication store).

Comment: I have the same issue. Why isn't it a standard behavioural - do not produce event if result of aggergation is equal the old entity?